# Open subset of a zero-dimensional homogeneous space is homogeneous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In an article I'm studying they say that the following statement is folklore:

*Any open subset of a zero-dimensional homogeneous topological space is homogeneous.*

Here zero-dimensional means that the space admits a base consisting of clopen sets and homogeneous means that for any pair of points in the space there is a self-homeomorphism of the space sending one of the two points to the other.

I don't know how to prove it nor where to find it.

I only need it for the case of separable metrizable spaces. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: [This surbey paper](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.vanmill/papers/papers2014/ArhangMillRecentProgressIII.pdf) indirectly discusses this. Look for SLH and coset spaces etc.